# Prove that the mean deviation for $x$ is equal to the mean deviation for $y$

Tags: statistics, means

Prove that the mean deviation for $y$ is equal to the mean deviation for $x$, i.e., 
$$
\mu.D_y = \mu.D_x 
$$
if 
$$
y_{i} = x_{i} \pm 3 ,\mbox{ where } i=1,2,\ldots, n,   
$$
and $x_i$ are ungrouped data.

$\textbf{Attempt}$: 
\begin{align*}
\mu.D_y &= \mu.D_x \\ 
\dfrac{\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^n} |y_i-\overline{y}|}{n} 
&= \dfrac{\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^n} |x_i-\overline{x}|}{n} \\ 
\sum_{i=1}^{n}|(x_i\pm 3)-\overline{y}| 
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n}|(y_i\pm 3)-\overline{x}| \\   
\end{align*}

I'm trying to prove it like this, but I don't know how to complete the solution.

Comment: Please type your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of posting a link. Moreover, please provide more details, for instance, what are your thoughts about the question, what you have tried, where you are stuck.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics StackExchange. We use MathJax to represent data and equations. An excellent guide is at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: Sahiba Arora ,, I'm edit question and show how i think about it

Answer (score 1):

Let $\overline{x}$ be the mean of ungrouped data $x_1,\ldots, x_n$. Then the mean deviation for $x_i$ is
$$
\mu.D_x = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i-\overline{x}|. 
$$
Suppose $y_i=x_i+3$ for each $1\leq i\leq n$. Then the mean for $y_i$ is
$$
\color{blue}{\overline{y}}
=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i  
=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i+3)
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i  + \frac{3n}{n} \color{blue}{= \overline{x} + 3}.   
$$
Thus the mean deviation for $y_i$ simplifies as 
\begin{align*}
\mu.D_y &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n |y_i-\overline{y}| \\ 
&=  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n |(x_i+3)-(\overline{x}+3)| \\ 
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-\overline{x}| \\ 
&= \mu.D_x. 
\end{align*}

We obtain a similar result if $y_i=x_i-3$ for each $1\leq i\leq n$.